# had started or started

Tags: past-tense

Despite the affluence , there was nothing creative happening for a young person in Dorridge . For those of us with any imagination , it was a cultural desert,  so we had to make our own entertainment. As a tiny child, I **had started**  to express my self by painting  and drawing on the walls and floor of the house, if I wasn't closely watched, and I would get spanked for instinctive efforts at self expression

extract  from SWELL MAPS 1972 1980 a book  by JOWE HEAD

I think that "started " could fit here because it seems to be evident that his capacity for imagination came first before "to be spanked" further more it is written as a tiny child that indicates clearly the moment it happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He is talking about being a 'young person', presumably a teenager or young adult; then he mentions a much earlier period when he was a 'tiny child'. The 'starting to express himself by painting' came long before the 'making our own entertainment'.

Answer (score 0):

Using the past perfect tense to talk about his early life implies that he's contextualizing a later period in the past which is his actual focus.

Without knowing what comes after this excerpt, I would strongly expect it to be a later and possibly more extended anecdote directly influenced by this information. Conversely, the simple past would lead me to expect an extended focus on the early period.